# Get the size of an attachment using IMAP on GMAIL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, gmail-imap

I would like to retrieve the size of each mail's attachment without having to download the file to get it. I'm using the [Gmail gem](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail).

EDIT: I'm looking for a way, to get the size only by reading the headers or similar without having to retrieve the whole attachments which is a very long process.

```
gmail = Gmail.connect(:xoauth, self.email, 
  :token           => self.token,
  :secret          => self.secret,
  :consumer_key    => 'SECRET',
  :consumer_secret => 'SECRET'
)
mails = gmail.mailbox("[Gmail]/All Mail").emails
mails.each do |mail|
  next if mail.message.attachments.blank?
  # How to get the message's size if possible ?
  mail.message.attachments.each do |attachment|
    # How to get the attachment's size ?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did. I used StringIO to convert the attachment to a file in memory and then took the size:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gmail'
require 'ap' #awesome_print gem

gmail = Gmail.connect("name","password") #simple authorization
mails = gmail.mailbox("[Gmail]/All Mail").emails
mails.each do |mail|
  next if mail.message.attachments.blank?
  mail.message.attachments.each do |attachment|
    file = StringIO.new(attachment.to_s)
    ap file.size
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this approach is too slow. I mean, is there a way to know the attachments without having to download the attachments ? Just by fetching the headers or something else ?

Comment: Not that I can tell... there is not an attr for size nor a method on the Mail::Part class. This at least stops the full download and pulls the object into memory

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will validate your answer in a couple days if no one else reply :-)

Comment: Thanks... and I am sorry there was nothing simpler... there is an @length attr nested deep in the object but for every attachment I had it came up as 0. Not sure what it is for.